# Problem installing MinionPro GNU/Linux [Solved]

Tags: texlive, linux, minionpro, installing-fonts

I have Chakra Linux in the laptop and I'm trying to install MinionPro package in TeX Live 2016 (installed from https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html) following the steps in https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/

After run `updmap-sys` this is the output:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
updmap [ERROR]: The following map file(s) couldn't be found:
updmap [ERROR]:         MinionPro.map (in /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg)
updmap [ERROR]: Did you run mktexlsr?

       You can disable non-existent map entries using the option
        --syncwithtrees.
```

And if I run `updmap-sys --enable Map=MinionPrp.map` the output is:

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg unchanged.  Map files not recreated.

updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

Seeing this line `dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"` I copy `metrics-base/fonts/map/dvips/MinionPro/MinionPro.map` file (from https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/) into `/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap` and the output is

```
updmap will read the following updmap.cfg files (in precedence order):
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg
updmap may write changes to the following updmap.cfg file:
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-config/web2c/updmap.cfg
dvips output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap"
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"

updmap is creating new map files
using the following configuration:
  LW35 font names                  : URWkb (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  prefer outlines                  : true (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  texhash enabled                  : true
  download standard fonts (dvips)  : true (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  download standard fonts (pdftex) : true (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  jaEmbed replacement string       : ipaex (/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-dist/web2c/updmap.cfg)
  jaVariant replacement string     : <empty> (default)
  scEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  tcEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  koEmbed replacement string       : noEmbed (default)
  create a mapfile for pxdvi       : false (default)

Scanning for LW35 support files  [  3 files]
Scanning for MixedMap entries    [ 44 files]
Scanning for KanjiMap entries    [ 11 files]
Scanning for Map entries         [266 files]

Generating output for dvipdfmx...
Generating output for ps2pk...
Generating output for dvips...
Generating output for pdftex...

Files generated:
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvips/updmap:
      15796 2017-03-31 23:02:46 builtin35.map
      21269 2017-03-31 23:02:46 download35.map
    2126617 2017-03-31 23:02:47 psfonts_pk.map
    2387512 2017-03-31 23:02:46 psfonts_t1.map
    2382318 2017-03-31 23:02:46 ps2pk.map
         14 2017-03-31 23:02:47 psfonts.map -> psfonts_t1.map
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap:
    2382325 2017-03-31 23:02:47 pdftex_dl14.map
    2380660 2017-03-31 23:02:47 pdftex_ndl14.map
         15 2017-03-31 23:02:47 pdftex.map -> pdftex_dl14.map
 /usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap:
       7884 2017-03-31 23:02:46 kanjix.map

Transcript written on "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/web2c/updmap.log".
updmap: Updating ls-R files.
```

This no solved the problem and I was looking the lines

```
pdftex output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/pdftex/updmap"
dvipdfmx output dir: "/usr/local/texlive/2016/texmf-var/fonts/map/dvipdfmx/updmap"
```

in the first output showed here, but into metrics-base folder I have no something related with these lines.

I remember I installed MinionPro in TeX Live 2016 when I had Ubuntu 14.04 in 32bit PC following the same steps and I had no problems.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: (1) do you have the fonts and where are they placed? (2) where is that particular map file located? kpsewhich should be able to find it. The output if updmap-sys seems to suggest the map file was not found, though not giving an error is a bit odd.

Comment: Have you tried installing `ttf-adobe-fonts` (if not in repos, then from AUR)?

Comment: You should try the scripts from https://github.com/sebschub/FontPro.

Comment: @daleif yes I have followed exactly the same steps as in a previous installation, but this time no works.

Comment: @TeXnician no, I don't have.

Comment: @ChristianClason in readme file, the building section is only for Windows user?

Comment: @TeXnician no, I don't have that fonts. I had no good experiences importing to ccr from aur.

Comment: If you don't have the fonts for Minion Pro, you can't install them. It sounds as if you did not install the support package properly. However, doing that on its own is not enough. You need the fonts in a suitable format and you need to match the fonts' version to the support package. There are a bunch of different versions floating around. They all require you to convert the fonts. Note that recent versions supplied with Adobe Reader are subject to additional licensing restrictions which may make this illegal. (Possibly even without conversion, but I'm not a lawyer & this is not legal advice.)

Comment: What's `ccr`? Chakra? If you cannot comfortably use AUR packages and are restricted to what's in the main repositories, that is pretty limiting. In particular, packages currently in the main repositories may later be in AUR. If you can't use AUR, you then lose access to that software. But using an Arch derivative is a dangerous game in any case, as I'm sure you know.

Comment: @cfr I have the fonts and I follow the procedure here https://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/fonts/minionpro/ as on other occasions when I install minion pro. I had no good experiences with packages from aur another times.

Comment: You could also download the package from [here](https://aur.archlinux.org/packages/ttf-adobe-fonts/). Then you just have to follow the steps which should be given in a README-like file.

Comment: @juanuni No, the instructions work for Linux as well -- it's just that for Windows, extra steps are required that are explicitly mentioned.

Comment: @TeXnician I could install `ttf-adobe-fonts` but there is no major difference.

Comment: @ChristianClason yeah you are right. Well, I have a little problem with some otf: `MinionPro-MediumIt.otf` I have that font but appears error.

Comment: Which error? When you do what?

Comment: You should be installing everything under `/usr/local/texlive/texmf-local` and not into the main tree.

Comment: Well @cfr into `/usr/local/texlive/` I have two directories: `2016` and `texmf-local` ... TeX Live works without problems.

Comment: What I mean is that you shouldn't install manually under `2016/`, but only under `texmf-local/`.

Comment: Well, I had no before `2016/` ... I just install Tex Live following https://www.tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html

Comment: Thanks @cfr ... a comment from you in another place help me.

Comment: Can you write up an answer describing how you solved this, or should we just close?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the solution was found in the comments “from another place” (wherever that is).  It's therefore not helpful to others.